# Is there a way to user FULL Postgres SQL DB, not the embeded one for my JUnit 5

Tags: postgresql, junit5, spring-boot-test

When I am trying with the following configuration I am getting the following issue:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoConfigureTestDatabase.

My JUnit Test case is:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@DataJpaTest
//@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@SpringJUnitConfig
//@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class GuideRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private GuideRepository guideRepository;

    @Test
    void doesGuideContainsData() {
        assertTrue(guideRepository.doesGuideContainsData());
    }
}
```

My application.properties under Test looks like this:

```
##connect to postgres DB
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/somedb
spring.datasource.username=XXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXX
```

I did tried with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase.`

Comment: I don't think there is an embedded PostgreSQL database, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am getting the error :  Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class.

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue at adding the following annotations on the top of my Test class:

```
@DataJpaTest
*@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)*
@SpringJUnitConfig
//@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class GuideRepositoryTest
```